# Symfony form, create entity using existing children

Tags: php, forms, symfony, doctrine-orm

### Question

Im trying to find a way to use symfony forms to persist a new root entity with pre-existing children.

With things how they are currently it tries to persist a new JobName rather than acknowledge it's existing.

Im passing a new Job entity plus the array data of the updates required.
A jobName already exists with an id of 1 and name 'existing name' in the DB, I want it to pass a reference to it not persist a new one.

```
$data = ['jobName' => ['id' => 1, 'name' => 'existing name']]; // The job array object
$form = $this->formFactory->create(new JobType(), $jobEntity); // Pass the array to form
$form->submit($data); // Bind data
```

I could setup an event listener in the form and anytime an entity with an id NOT NULL is passed, grab the reference from the entity manager, but I did think this might work out of the box...

### Update

Switching JobType buildForm:

```
->add('jobName', EntityType::class, [
     'class' => 'AppBundle:JobName',
     'choice_label' => 'name',
 ])
```

and then the array to allows assigning existing names:

```
$data = ['jobName' => 1];
```

However now im unsure how I would create a new jobName (using cascade)?

### Reference Data

My tables are:

```
Job [id, job_name_id]  
JobName [id, name]
```

Job Form:

```
class JobType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('jobName', new JobNameType())
        ;
    }
    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults([
            'data_class' => 'AppBundle\Entity\Job',
            'csrf_protection' => false,
        ]);
    }
}
```

JobName Form:

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('id')
            ->add('name')
        ;
    }

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults([
                'data_class' => 'AppBundle\Entity\JobName',
            ]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Try getting a reference for `JobName` with manager's `find()` method and then use `$jobEntity->setJobName()` for instance to add a reference to the entity and save it that way, instead passing an array.

Comment: The array must stay an array, as its a json payload - this is a rest app

Comment: If you pass an array remove the `data_class` option

Comment: The passed data is an entity, the array is passed to the form handle method